# Trying to update the mysql table with user friendly input using string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

Though it is a repeated question , but want to know where my code is wrong as I am facing a syntax error .

```
def update_block():
    table_name = input("Enter the name of the table: ")
    column_update = input("Enter the column name to be updated: ")
    column_name = input("Enter the column where the operation is to be performed: ")
    name = input("Enter the name has to get update: ")
    column_value = input("Enter the column value: ")


    try:
       
        sql_update_query = f"""Update {table_name} set {column_update} = %s where {column_name} = %s"""
        inputData = (f"{name},{column_value}" )
        my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query,inputData)
        mydb.commit()
        print("Record Updated successfully ")

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to update record to database: {}".format(error))
    finally:
        if (mydb.is_connected()):
            my_cursor.close()
            mydb.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")

update_block()
```

error i am getting as :

Failed to update record to database: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s where prj_id = %s' at line 1
MySQL connection is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f"""Update {table_name} set {column_update} = %s where {column_name} = %s"""
```

You used f strings with curly brackets and %s notation here. Do either one and it should work

e.g.:

```
f"""Update {table_name} set {column_update} = {name} where {column_name} = {column_value}"""
```

Comment: You also wouldnt need the next variable "input_data" anymore and change my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query,inputData) to my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query)

Comment: Maybe I am also on the wrong path here, just never seen it the way you do it.

Comment: it comes with a new error as "1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'VPN' in 'field list'" . Here new name i am setting as "VPN".   Please see the data i am trying to update with  .   Enter the name of the table: block
Enter the column name to be updated: block_name
Enter the name has to get update: VPN
Enter the column where the operation is to be performed: prj_rev_id
Enter the column value: 7903
Failed to update record to database: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'VPN' in 'field list'

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand. Please edit your question and try to give examples of what you want to do, like before and after.

Comment: Any updates? If I was able to help you please mark your question as answered :)

Comment: Ya Dustin, Solution provided by you was correct. I inserted a wrong data.. later on 
 I corrected it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with the code.

In this line,

```
sql_update_query = f"""Update {table_name} set {column_update} = %s where {column_name} = %s"""
```

the table and column names should be quoted with backticks (`` "`" ``) to handle names containing spaces or hyphens (or some unicode characters).  So the line would look like this.

```
sql_update_query = f"""Update `{table_name}` set `{column_update}` = %s where `{column_name}` = %s"""
```

Note that the placeholders for variables should remain as `%s`.

In this line

```
inputData = (f"{name},{column_value}" )
```

the variables' values are being converted to strings within a single string.  But the statement expects *two* variables, not one.  Also, it is better<sup>*</sup> to pass the raw variables to the database connection and let the connection manage formatting them correctly in the final query.  So the line should be

```
inputData = (name, column_value)
```

And now the statement can be executed with the related variables

```
my_cursor.execute(sql_update_query, inputData)
```

<sup>*</sup> The driver knows how to correctly convert Python data types into those expected by the database, and how to escape and quote these values.  This provides at least two benefits:

- it helps prevent SQL injection attacks, where a malicious user provides an SQL statement as a variable value (such as `"; DELETE FROM mytable;"`
- it ensures that values are processed as expected; consider this statement:

```sql
SELECT '2020-09-01' AS `Quoted Date`, 2020-09-01 AS `Unquoted Date`;
+-------------+---------------+
| Quoted Date | Unquoted Date |
+-------------+---------------+
| 2020-09-01  |          2010 |
+-------------+---------------+
```